# How do I make a batch file that can run a program with a certain gpu?

Tags: gpu

How do I create a batch file that can run a program with a certain graphics processor(Nvidia)? Examples would help. Thanks

Comment: Why do you have a requirement for a specific GPU?

Comment: I have this option when right click on applications - run with graphics processor -> high-performance nvidia processor but on batch file I have not this option :( my batch run one application